# How to get which dom element is clicked which is not having id

Tags: jquery

In my HTML code I have 3 span elements with same class as 'delete-span' but with none of them have id attribute. I have a click function on class selector of span. In click function how do I know which of these span is clicked.?

Comment: `this` references the dom element that was clicked

Comment: show your efforts first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.delete-span').click(function() {
    $(this).remove(); // <-- your span
});
```